# How can i navigate user to same page when the errors occurs in multer upload nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I am doing some experiment over nodejs for my new project and doing it on Image upload. I am using Express MVC with mongodb. I want to send user back to same page with validation errors from multer configuration itself. There is no response parameter in `filename` function of multer.

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function (request, file, callback) {
    callback(null, 'public/uploads/');
 },
    filename: function (request, file, callback) {// Validations & File Name can be set/changed here
    if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg') {
        console.log('File extensions required are png, jpg, jpeg');
        return false;
    } else {
        var rString = randomString.generate({ length: 12, charset: 'alphabetic' });
        callback(null, rString + '_' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
}
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('displayImage');
```

My route is

```
router.route('/change-avatar')
.get(function (req, res) {
    res.render('views/profile/changeAvatar');
})
.post(function (req, res) {
    var id = req.session.userId;
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); return; } // if error
        console.log(req.files);
        response.end('Your File Uploaded');
        console.log('Photo Uploaded');
    });
});
```

How could it be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At least show what error you get instead of show 'Error Occured'.

But I guest the problem is destination path not exists.

Try put below code before 'var storage'

```
require('mkdirp').sync('./public/uploads/enduser')
```

remember to

```
npm i mkdirp --save
```